# prometheus cpu usage per process consider cores

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-process-exporter

Hi i figured out following querys:

find cpu usage in sec per process and node

```
sum(rate(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{instance=~"tango.*"}[5m])) by (instance, groupname)
```

get number of cpu cores per node

```
count(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance=~"tango.*",job="node"}) without (mode, cpu, job)
```

How can i do a query like:
The cpu usage in percent per node consider the cores of node (to not get values over 100)

```
sum(rate(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{instance=~"rcsecho.*"}[5m])) by (groupname) / count(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="INSTANCE_FROM_FIRST_QUERY",job="rcs-node-info"}) without (mode, cpu, job) * 100
```

To get a result like:

- tango1  processA  12%
- tango1  processB  25%
- tango2  processA  11%
- tango2  processB  23%